# Trying to make the python shell go full screen upon launch and also make a popup image go straight into full screen

Tags: python, subprocess, fullscreen

I'm working on some extra curricular work for school and attempting to implement images into my game of hangman , the main issues I am having is when opening the image it is opening behind the shell and as such can't be noticed. I'm hoping to be doing it with the subprocess library -  subprocess.call("taskkill /f /im Microsoft.Photos.exe" , shell=True) - in a similar way to how the window is shut afterwards.

Along with this , when using  - print('\n' * 100) - to hide the word which the users will guess , my text begins to go offscreen which is easily fixed by making the window fill the screen but just wondering if there is an easier , automated way to do this through python ?

Comment: Have you considered using `Tkinter` or another GUI library? Also why print out the answer to begin with?

Comment: As in using Tkinter to load the image ? Would that then bring the image up above the shell ? The answers inputed as I've made an option for single or multiplayer as we were told to try and make it stand out as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using cv2 library, for example :

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("face.jpg")

cv2.imshow("Gray", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This will show the photo on the screen untill you press a key to destroy it.

You can also change the photo resolution with cv2.resize(image,x,y) and check the image current resolution with image.shape()

Comment: Glad that helped :)